# How can i retain specific characters in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove certain words or characters from a sentence with some exceptions using regular expression.

For example- I have a string `this is [/.] a string [ra] with [/] something`, I want to remove `[ra]`, `[/.]` but not `[/]`.

I used:

```
m = re.sub('\[.*?\]','',n)
```

which works fine, how can I retain this-> `[/]`

Comment: `new_string=old_string.replace('[ra'],'').replace('[/.]','')` is an answer to the question you asked. If that's not what you want, I suggest asking a question more precise that just a list of things you do and don't want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\[(?!/])[^][]*]', '', n)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgQK4q/1).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?!/])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `/]` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern `\[(?!\/\])[^\]]+\]` and replace all matches with empty string.

Explanation: it matches `[` with `\[`, then it assures, that what follows is NOT `\]`, so we don't match `[\]`, it's done with negative lookahead: `(?!\/\])`, then it matches everything until `]` and `]` itself with pattern `[^\]]+\]` (`[^\]]+` matches one or more characters other then `]`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTWJ1W/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation to capture in a group what you want to keep and match what you want to remove.

```
result = re.sub(r"(\[/])|\[[^]]+\]", r"\1", n)
```

**Explanation**

`(\[/])|\[[^]]+\]`

- `(\[/])` Capture `[/]` in a group
- `|` Or
- `\[[^]]+\]` Match an opening square bracket until a closing square bracket using a negated character class

Replace with the first capturing group `\1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaBLNy/1)

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/OUNWI89655)